# I am creating an ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC project. I want to filter the list of products when check the checkBox of Men the than show only men products

Tags: asp.net-core

How can I filter the product list when product checkBox true l_ModUDFItem is the list of the products and in this code products are show with input check box.

I want to filter the product when I check the men group.

```html
<div class="single-widget category">
    <h3 class="title">@Model.l_ModUDF.Where(x => x.UDFType == "String").FirstOrDefault().UDFID</h3>
    <ul>
        @foreach (var item in Model.l_ModUDFItem.GroupBy(x => x.Category))
        {
            l_ModUDFItem = item.Where(x => x.Category == item.Key).First() ;
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox"
                       name="model"
                       value="" 
                       onclick="Categories(@l_ModUDFItem.Category)"/>
                @item.Key
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You can try to add onclick event to checkbox,and get data with ajax as `regestea23` said.

Answer (score 0):

asp.net core is not a single page framework  and you need to use ajax in your page